# Converting a VARCHAR ',96' into integer 0.96 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have to do the conversion as mentioned in the title, I tried a lot of things and couldn't find the solution yet.

Any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: You are never going to "convert a VARCHAR ',96' to integer 0.96" because 0.96 is not an integer.

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to replace , with dot and do convert as below:

```
declare @v varchar(10) = ',96'
select converT(float, replace(@v,',','.'))
```

I think in your question you mentioned as integer, in this case it will be ZERO because it will take floor value and not consider the round, hence left to float and you can decide on required approach

Comment: Maybe it's a regional setting but this http://rextester.com/RSUVF33521 stills hows a comma.

Comment: Many Thanks!!!! Yes. its a Float, my bad. 

Thax for the solution again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');
        -> 'MySQL'
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', NULL, 'QL');
        -> NULL
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(14.3);
        -> '14.3'
```